# Equivalent Postgres query for an Oracle query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

Which Postgres query is equivalent to the following Oracle query?

```
select CID,
  max(cus.customer_id)  keep (dense_rank first order by decode(acct.CUS_Type,'X',4,'M',5,'F',6,'G',7,'I',5,6), start_date)  best_CUS
  from cusomer cus
    group by CID ;
```

Comment: I usually say "well, what did you try" for this sort of thing, but fair enough - that's using a lot of Oracle-isms. Look into PostgreSQL's `dense_rank` window function, and the `CASE` statement. No time to give a detailed answer now. In general it's nice if you mention your PostgreSQL version, and if possible show some table definitions and sample data to go with your queries (for easier answer testing). See http://sqlfiddle.com/ for the latte.r

Comment: Voting to close since OP does not cooperate and provide requested information. A table definition and a description would be the bare minimum.